# How to include image in input value

Tags: html, css, input

You will see in the snippet that I have two buttons. One called "Not Included" and the other "Included". The included button is how I want an `input type="submit"` button to work. I am not sure how to put an image after the value.

Is this possible and how would I do it?

```css
.bigButtonLink {
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 50px auto;
}
.bigButton {
 border: 1px solid #BE1E2D;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 border-radius: 2px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background: #FFF;
 font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
 color: #B82222; 
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 border: 2px solid #B82222;
 font-size: 2.3rem;
 padding: 3rem 6rem 3rem 4.5rem;
}
.rightArrowR {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 margin-left: 17px;
 transition: all .35s ease;-webkit-transition: all .35s ease;
}
.bigButton:hover .rightArrowR {
 background-size: 15px 15px;
 background-repeat: none;
 transition: all .35s ease;-webkit-transition: all .35s ease;
 transform: translateX(15px);-webkit-transform: translateX(15px);
}
```

```html
<p>Not Included</p>
<input name="submit" id="quoteSubmit" class="block bigButton" type="submit" value="SEND PROJECT QUOTE">
<p>Included</p>
<a href="#" class="bigButtonLink bigButton">
  Request Quote <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-arrow-forward-512.png" class="rightArrowR">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible for you to use `button type='submit'` instead of `input type='submit'`? I slightly changed your snippet below. Yon can use it for normal submit action.

```css
.bigButtonLink {
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 50px auto;
}
.bigButton {
 border: 1px solid #BE1E2D;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 border-radius: 2px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background: #FFF;
 font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
 color: #B82222; 
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 border: 2px solid #B82222;
 font-size: 2.3rem;
 padding: 3rem 6rem 3rem 4.5rem;
}
.rightArrowR {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 margin-left: 17px;
 transition: all .35s ease;-webkit-transition: all .35s ease;
}
.bigButton:hover .rightArrowR {
 background-size: 15px 15px;
 background-repeat: none;
 transition: all .35s ease;-webkit-transition: all .35s ease;
 transform: translateX(15px);-webkit-transform: translateX(15px);
}
```

```html
<p>Not Included</p>
<input name="submit" id="quoteSubmit" class="block bigButton" type="submit" value="SEND PROJECT QUOTE">
<p>Included</p>
<button type="submit" class="bigButtonLink bigButton">
  Request Quote <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-arrow-forward-512.png" class="rightArrowR">
</button>
```

Comment: @Paul Glad to help you.